# merge mutliple excel files into one excel workbook but different worksheets using bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How can i merge multiple excel files into one excel workbook but different worksheets using bash scripting

```
    > input: file1_1234.xlsx
             file2_1234.xlsx 
             file3_9999.xlsx 
             file4_1245.xlsx
             file5_9999.xlsx 
             file6_1245.xlsx
```

output:

```
**outputfile_1234.xlsx** which contains 
file1_1234.xlsx
file2_1234.xlsx in two different worksheets


**outputfile_9999.xlsx** which contains 
file3_9999.xlsx
file5_9999.xlsx in two different worksheets


**outputfile_1245.xlsx** which contains 
file4_1245.xlsx
file6_1245.xlsx in two different worksheets
```

Comment: You can do it in three steps: a) converting the `*.xslx` files into `*.fods` using LibreOffice headless (i.e. from the command line) with the command `soffice --headless --convert-to fods *.xlsx`; b) the resulting files are plain XML files which can be merged into one FODS file using tools as `xsltproc`; c) convert the resulting FODS file again to XLSX with the command above (see: a).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.

I once was able to merge two FODS spreadsheets (which stands for Flat Open Document Spreadsheet) into one using xsltproc. Both spreadsheets were simple and very similar. I don't know if this will work with every kind of spreadsheet.

So, it is necessary first to transform the XLSX spreadsheets into FODS spreadsheets, issuing:

```sh
soffice --headless --convert-to fods file*.xlsx
```

The command xsltproc needs a stylesheet as argument, which is next XSL program:

**tablemerge.xsl:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
  xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
  xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
  xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
  xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
  xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0"
  xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0"
  xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0"
  xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0"
  xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0"
  xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0"
  xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
  xmlns:config="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:config:1.0"
  xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office"
  xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer"
  xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc"
  xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:rpt="http://openoffice.org/2005/report"
  xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#"
  xmlns:tableooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/table"
  xmlns:drawooo="http://openoffice.org/2010/draw"
  xmlns:calcext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:calc:xmlns:calcext:1.0"
  xmlns:loext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:office:xmlns:loext:1.0"
  xmlns:field="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooo-ms-interop:xmlns:field:1.0"
  xmlns:formx="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooxml-odf-interop:xmlns:form:1.0"
  xmlns:css3t="http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/" 
  office:version="1.2" 
  office:mimetype="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet">

  <xsl:template match="table:table">
    <!-- copy table:table from main file -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <table:table 
      table:name="{document($secondfile)//table:table/@table:name}" 
      table:style-name="{document($secondfile)//table:table/@table:style-name}">
    <!-- copy table:table from second file -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="document($secondfile)//table:table/child::*" />
    </table:table>
  </xsl:template>

   <!-- default template: identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSL program must be invoked as follows:

```sh
xsltproc --stringparam secondfile file2.fods tablemerge.xsl file1.fods > mergedtables.fods
```

Now, the script to connect all these parts together could be:

**script:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

soffice --headless --convert-to fods file*.xlsx

for key in $(ls file*.xlsx | cut -d . -f 1 | cut -d _ -f 2 | sort -u)
do
  outputfile=outputfile_$key.fods
  inputfiles=( file*_$key.fods )
  maininputfile=${inputfiles[0]}
  secondinputfile=${inputfiles[1]}

  xsltproc --stringparam secondfile $secondinputfile tablemerge.xsl $maininputfile

  soffice --headless --convert-to xslx outputfile*.fods
done
```