# Merging *.fods using xsltproc to generate worbook with multiple sheets

Tags: excel, xml, unix, xslt, csh

I have several excel worksheets in unix environment.
My goal is to merge them into one single workbook in unix environment itself.

I found a found solution using xsltproc which sort of works, but doesnt do the job completely.
([merge mutliple excel files into one excel workbook but different worksheets using bash scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458267/merge-mutliple-excel-files-into-one-excel-workbook-but-different-worksheets-usin))

Here's my current workflow as per the answer provided in the above link :

1. Convert each *.xlsx sheet to *.fods files

`soffice --headless --convert-to fods file*.xlsx`

2. Use xsltproc to merge *.fods sheets one by one, to get a workbook which will contain all sheets.
3. Convert the *.fods workbook back to *.xlsx using below command :

`soffice --headless --convert-to xslx outputfile*.fods`

The place I'm stuck is at #2.
The original answer in the link provides a xsltproc based solution which can merge two sheets.
I am trying to extend it incrementally by below method :

`xsltproc --stringparam secondfile file2.fods tablemerge.xsl file1.fods > int_2.fods`

`xsltproc --stringparam secondfile file3.fods tablemerge.xsl int_2.fods > final.fods`

It works perfectly as long as **only 2 sheets** are to be combined, but behaves unexpectedly the moment I try to add file3.fods to the intermediate file int_2.fods.

The problem I see is the final.fods contains two copies of the worksheet in file3.fods .

I suspect its a problem with the `tablemerge.xsl`  file, which contains contains some xml syntax (below) towards the end. The issue is I dont have any clue how xml works, but the syntax seems not very complicated. Any help to suggest what modification is required in below code will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

**tablemerge.xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
  xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
  xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
  xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
  xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
  xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0"
  xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0"
  xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0"
  xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0"
  xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0"
  xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0"
  xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
  xmlns:config="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:config:1.0"
  xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office"
  xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer"
  xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc"
  xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:rpt="http://openoffice.org/2005/report"
  xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#"
  xmlns:tableooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/table"
  xmlns:drawooo="http://openoffice.org/2010/draw"
  xmlns:calcext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:calc:xmlns:calcext:1.0"
  xmlns:loext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:office:xmlns:loext:1.0"
  xmlns:field="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooo-ms-interop:xmlns:field:1.0"
  xmlns:formx="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooxml-odf-interop:xmlns:form:1.0"
  xmlns:css3t="http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/" 
  office:version="1.2" 
  office:mimetype="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet">

  <xsl:template match="table:table">
    <!-- copy table:table from main file -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <table:table 
      table:name="{document($secondfile)//table:table/@table:name}" 
      table:style-name="{document($secondfile)//table:table/@table:style-name}">
    <!-- copy table:table from second file -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="document($secondfile)//table:table/child::*" />
    </table:table>
  </xsl:template>

   <!-- default template: identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit1**

Not sure how to completely describe what i see but i'll give it a try.

I manually created a workbook with two sheets, and saved it as xlsx, followed by conversion to *.fods.  Then i compare this new fods to the one which is generated from single worksheet. It does seem to indicate to me what exactly i need.

Inside the fods file, i see the below :

#1. In fods from single sheet , I see only one table:table section :

```
....
  <office:spreadsheet>
   <table:calculation-settings table:case-sensitive="false" table:automatic-find-labels="false" table:use-regular-expressions="false" table:use-wildcards="true"/>
   <table:table table:name="Sheet1" table:style-name="ta1">
    ........
   </table:table>
   <table:named-expressions/>
  </office:spreadsheet>
...
```

#2. In *.fods from two sheets , I see only **two** table:table sections :

```
....
  <office:spreadsheet>
   <table:calculation-settings table:case-sensitive="false" table:automatic-find-labels="false" table:use-regular-expressions="false" table:use-wildcards="true"/>
   <table:table table:name="Sheet1" table:style-name="ta1">
    ........
   </table:table>
   <table:table table:name="Sheet2" table:style-name="ta2">
    .......
   </table:table>
   <table:named-expressions/>
  </office:spreadsheet>
...
```

I guess what i'm looking for is a **tablemerge.xsl** which can help me to merge two *.fods as in #1, and get something similar to *.fods in #2.
Ofcourse the complication is that one of the *.fods being input can contain multiple sheets, and the final output *.fods should just concatenate the table:table section from second file into the first *.fods.

Comment: It would help if we could see (a) what a single .fods file looks like after conversion from .xslx and (b) what the combined .fods file should look like after all the files have been merged.

Comment: @michael.hor257k
 (a) what a single .fods looks like--> Its like an excel worksheet. It looks exactly like the xlsx sheet if you open it using soffice. The *.fods file seems to be an open format , and file can be opened using text editor. (b)what the combined .fods should look like --> It should look just like a excel workbook with separate sheets for each of the files which have been used in merge operation.

Comment: I am not asking how it looks when you open it in an office application. I am asking what it looks like when you open it in a text editor and look at the actual XML code. And by "looks like" I mean show us the actual code, do not describe it. --- In your place I would create a file with a single sheet and convert it to .fods. Then add another sheet or two and convert that too. Comparing the two files should tell you what is the parent element of sheets. That is the element you need to match and make it copy its existing sheet/s + the other file's sheet/s.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I just edited the question to add the detail you asked. Please let me know if its what you're looking for

Comment: @avr: [tag:gnumeric] has a [utility](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/ssconvert.1.html) with a merge option: `ssconvert --export-type='Gnumeric_Excel:xlsx' --merge-to=fn0.xlsx -- fn1.xlsx fn2.xlsx fn3.xlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly guesswork because we don't know the exact specification for a .fods file - and you're not even showing us a complete example. Try perhaps:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0">

<xsl:param name="secondfile"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="office:spreadsheet">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document($secondfile)//table:table" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This may or may not work depending on what role the other child elements of `office:spreadsheet` (namely `table:calculation-settings` and `table:named-expressions`) play in this, as well as other factors that I am not able to predict.

I am not even sure how you can test reliably that the result "works"; you may get the sheets from the other files, but they may be missing some functionality.